# Python: Overflow Sum

Tags: python

A list of numbers L is given, along with one other numeric parameter, *threshold*. The problem is to return the smallest positive integer k so that summing the first k inverted items in : is bigger than *threshold* (or, if no such k can be found return -1).

Example:

```
>>> M = [0.5, 3.5, 2.0, 7.0, 1.0]
>>> overflow(M, 10)
-1
>>> overflow(M, 2.5)
3
>>> overflow(M, 2.2)
2
```

I am not good at writing code and don't really understand it at all.

I know you need to do for example (`A / A**A`) to get the  multiplicative inverse then add them together. That needs to continue until A>M (threshold). Return -1 if all  multiplicative inverse don't exceed M. Then return the amount of numbers you added together. I just don't know how to put it all together.

Comment: `1./A` is a lot easier than `A/(A*A)` - and `A/A**A` is way off.  Start coding!  Post when you have something to show.

Comment: Is that example correct?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, if you're the inspectorG4dget who wrote Pyvolytion, then yes.  timsort was just another sorting algorithm ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters: yup that's me! I wrote that to make coding homework assignments (and later, my master's thesis) easier. You just made my  <virtualHandshake>! (Sorry, I'll stop fangirling now)

Answer (score 0):

```
def overflow(L, threshold):
  total = 0
  for i,num in enumerate(L):
    total += 1.0/num
    if total > threshold:
      return i
  return -1
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but what is (i,num)?...Because I have yet to use enumerate could I use range(len(L))?

Comment: Yes. `for i in range(len(L))` and `num = L[i]` can together replace the call to enumerate

Comment: It is giving me the error

File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: overflow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'threshold'

Where would I add threshold in to eliminate this error?